# How to query rows "where id IN [some-array-of-numbers]" in azure mobile services (server scripts)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

My task is to query `deviceTokens` from my `clientDevices` table by given list of IDs. And then send push notifications to that clients.

I am getting the list of IDs by inserting the following data to `pushRequests` table:

```
{
  "alert": "Hello customer!",
  "badge": 1,
  "recipients": [2, 4, 5]
}
```

And I wrote this server side insert function:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
  if (item.recipients) {
    tables.getTable('clientDevices').where(function(ids) {
      return (ids.indexOf(this.id) > -1)
    }, item.recipients).read({
      success: function(results) {
        // . . .
        // Send push notifications to this guys
        // . . .
      }
    })
    item.recipients = JSON.stringify(item.recipients)
  }
  request.execute()
}
```

But I get a strange error:

```
Error in script '/table/pushRequests.insert.js'. Error: The expression 'ids.indexOf(this.id)'' is not supported.
```

If `indexOf` function is not supported, then how can I make "field IN array" style filter? Can I pass an array to `mssql.query(sql, params, options)` as a query parameter?

*PS: I would really like not to build manually a where expresion from the given array.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Mobile Services LINQ-style syntax for JS with the in operator, example:

```
// find all TodoItem records with id = 2 or 3
var todos = tables.getTable("TodoItem");
todos.where(function(arr) {
    return this.id in arr;
}, [2, 3]).read({
    success: console.log(results);
});
```

The syntax is:

```
table.where(function, parameters).read(options);
```

Where the function is similar to a lambda that returns true or false by comparing properties on the current row (this). The one weird thing is that parameters have to specified as parameters on the function signature and passed in separately, as you can see with the 2 and 3 above.

Comment: Wow! thanks, it works!
It does not look like "traditional" javascript function, to me, though :-)
Can you advice, where can I read more about it?
Why did they choose to use this kind of style? And what more limitations has where-function?

And once more, thanks a lot!

Comment: This code doesn't work. The success callback must be a function, not just `console.log(results)`. `results` is `undefined`

Comment: This solved my problem.  I have been searching for an example of in or contains functionality with azure mobile services with javascript backend.  I tried the same thing as the original poster, received the same error message which led me to this so question and answer.

Comment: for the new azure app service, please remove `.read({success:console.log(results); });`